# how to change url from http://www.mysite.com/mobile to http://mobile.mysite.com?

Tags: url

i have a directory on my server called mobile. basically if a user is accessing my site from a mobile device it will take them to http://www.mysite.com/mobile and in directory mobile is index.php.

but i was wondering how people change the browser url address, so instead of http://www.mysite.com/mobile its http://mobile.mysite.com.

can anyone please explain/show me how i can do this. thanks

Comment: what server software are you using? apache2, nginx, iis?

Comment: apache, hosting with go daddy

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to configure a subdomain, i.e. an A record with the DNS provider. If you have just one server/IP, point this A record to the same.
2. Configure a new virtual host on your webserver to respond to the A record you just created.